# Model is of different type than specified in using Statement MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have renamed my class from `MvcPatientLaboratoryResultsOfInterestViewModel` to `MvcPatientBloodResultsViewModel`.

The problem is as follow, as can be seen in this image. The type of `Model` in my razor view, does not correspond to the type I declared in the using statement.
[image]

I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name
>   'MvcPatientLaboratoryResultsOfInterestViewModel' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'EDR.Presentation.WebMain.ViewModels' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

I have Cleaned my solution, and tried to rebuild, to no success.

Why is this happening?

Comment: you have this error in VS compiler or when try to enter view?

Comment: When I try and compile the solution

Comment: Have you tried to close VS and open it again?

Comment: have you searched in your solution for the name "MvcPatientLaboratoryResultsOfInterestViewModel", to check if still exist some refernce to the old name class?

Comment: @DespeiL Closing and opening Visual Studio solved most of the issues, I was stuck with one, where I had to change some asp resource file. I will post an answer now, thanks

Comment: @DespeiL If you would like, you can add an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Often have the same Razor bug )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to reopen your VS studio

Comment: Even after cleaning solution, and rebuilding, this seemed to work.